# AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

i am a beginner in java, and i am trying to understand the problem in what my friend wrote, the problem from what i think is that the array size are different. if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

the problem

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at fmenu$fillbuttonListener.actionPerformed(fmenu.java:115)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

and here is where i think the problem is

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     Random randomNumbers = new Random();
     studentarray = new Object[numofstudent];
     quizarray = new Object[numofstudent][numofquiz]; //quizarray = new int[numofstudent][numofquiz]; (original)

     for(int i=0; i<numofstudent; i++)
     {
        quizarray[0][i] = baseid+i; 
        System.out.println(quizarray[0][i]);
        //studentarray[i] = baseid+i; 
        for(int j=1; j<numofquiz+1; j++)
        {
           int number = randomNumbers.nextInt(100);
           quizarray[j][i] = number;                       // row column
           System.out.println(quizarray[j][i]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: We don't know how large your two-dimensional array is.

Comment: FYI - it's telling you the error is on line 115. It would help if you point out which line 115 is.

Comment: quizarray[j][i] = number;  here is the line 115

Comment: Then I still think my answer is right. You appear to be swapping the student and quiz fields. That line would then be `quizarray[i][j]`, as `i` refers to a student and `j` refers to a quiz.

Answer (score 1):

You define:

```
quizarray = new Object[numofstudent][numofquiz]
```

But then access it using

```
quizarray[0][i]
```

Where `i` is < `numofstudent`. I think you just want:

```
quizarray[i][0]
```